# jquery if background is red doesn't recognize error, looks easy but stubborn

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**http://jsfiddle.net/TcSQ8/31/**

Why is this fiddle not working? interesting..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".box").click(function(){
      if ($(".box").css("background-color") == "red")
      {
          $(".box").html("Success!");
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: `console.log()` is your friend. Try to do `console.log($('.box').css('background-color'))` and see what it returns.

Comment: Happily. The code above a shows lack of effort. Looking at the jQuery api would easily resolve the `background` and `string` issue.

Comment: The downvotes come from the fact that the alert in your sample code above tells you exactly why the if check fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is this fiddle not working?

Many reasons.

1) CSS property `background` is not `background-color`

2) `background-color` is not `red` but `rgb(255, 0, 0)`

Working code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".box").click(function(){

      if ($(".box").css("background-color") == "rgb(255, 0, 0)")
      {
          $(".box").html("Success!");
      }
  });
});
```

[Working Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/TcSQ8/26/)

---

Side note: debugging with `console.log()` is much more convenient than `alert()`

Side note (2): you are able to debug if statement. In your case, a test like this would have solved the issue.

```
console.log($(".box").css("background") == "red")
```

Comment: @codinfreak they would benefit with the `console.log` if they wanted to learn, not copy pasta.

Answer (score 2):

if you just want to compare color, get `background-color`. After, use rgb code in your condition and it works.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".box").click(function(){
      if ($(".box").css("background-color") == "rgb(255, 0, 0)")
      {
          $(".box").append("Success!");
      }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".box").click(function(){
      alert($(".box").css("background-color"));
      if ($(".box").css("background-color") == "rgb(255, 0, 0)")
      {
          $(".box").html("Success!");
      }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Because:

1. You're comparing background (and not background-color) to a string (red).
2. both css('background') and css('backgroundColor') would return the computed rgb-value of the elements current background color. You're comparing it to a string.